# PHP Redirection Between Login & Other Pages

Tags: php, authentication

I am very new to PHP, and I'm having some issues understanding what I am doing wrong.

My issue is that I can't get past my login page. Every page that I try to access is redirecting to my login/home page.

This is the code for my login page:

```
<?php
session_start(); // start up your PHP session!
require_once ('includes/config.inc.php');
$page_title = 'Login'; 
include ('includes/header.html');
?>
</head>  
<body>
<?php
include ('includes/menus.html');
?>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br /> 
<br />


<div id="main"><div class="inner_copy"></div>
        <div id="right">
        <br></br>
            <h4>Welcome to Sopshin&#39;s Rental Tracker!</h4>
            <p>Sopshin&#39;s Rental Tracker is a Ft. Lauderdale, FL based <b>theatrical lighting and equipment</b> rental and distribution company. We offer a unique interactive rental catalogue that allows the renter to track where our equipment is, and when it will return to the shop. The theatre industry is constantly faced with the challenge of working during non-typical business hours. Now, from the comfort of your computer, and at any time of day, it is possible to see the full list of equipment we have available on the dates of your event. Please take a look around or site, and feel free to contact us if you have any questions. Thank you! </p>
            <h4>Our Promise...</h4>
            <p>Sopshin&#39;s Rental Tracker is proud to offer the best in stage lighting equipment. We rent equipment from many companies including Martin Lighting, High End Systems, Vari*Lite, ETC, Strand and more! </p>
            <p><b>We promise to offer you the best in customer service and lighting equipment at the lowest possible price. Our goal is to make your show or event a success in every way possible!</b></p>
        </div>
        <div id="left">
        <br></br>
            <h3>Registered User Sign In</h3>
            <center>To create an account, please <a href="register.php"> click here. </a></center>

<head>
<center>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Track form progress with <progress> - CodePen</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/indexlogin.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />


<body>
<?php
                if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
                ?>
                <div id="loginajax">
                <form>
                    <div align="center">
                            <input type='text' name='user_name' required='required' value='' class='Text' placeholder='Username' id='user_name' />
                         <input type='password' name='password' required='required' value='' class='password' placeholder='Enter Password' id='password' />
                          <div class="actions" div id="login">
                             <input name="commit" type="button" value="Login" class="login" onClick="loginUser();">
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                <?php
                } else {
                echo '<p class="welcome">Welcome ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '</p>';
                echo '<a href="logout.php", class="welcome">Logout<br></br></a>';
                echo '<p class="welcome">Click Here to View Account </p>';
                }
                ?>    
  </div>
  </body>
  </form>
        </br>
 </body>
            <h3>News & Updates</h3>
            <img src="images/S4Mini.jpg" alt="" title="" width="150" height="100" style=" float:left; padding-right: 20px; padding-left:15px;"/>
            <p>Sopshin&#39;s Rental Tracking is proud to announce that the <b>ETC Source 4 Mini</b> is now available for rental! <a href="ETC Source 4 Mini.html">Click here for more information.</a> </p>
</div>
        <?php
        include ('includes/footer.html');
        ?>
    <!-- end #page -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for the page that I am trying to access:

```
<?php
ob_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}
require_once ('includes/config.inc.php');
$page_title = 'Account History';
include ('includes/header.html');
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include ('includes/menus.html');
?>
<div id="main">
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
 <?php
    // Check if the employee is login:
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

        require_once ('mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to the db and creates      $dbc

        // Query the database:

        // Make the query:
        $id = $_SESSION['user'];
        $q = "SELECT `rental_ID`, `User_ID`, `date_out`, `date_in`, `price`, `venue`, `status` FROM `History` WHERE 1 ";

        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
        ?>


<center><IMG src="Images/Account History.png" width=175 height=40></IMG></center>
<h3><center><u>Renter:</u><?php echo $_SESSION['first_name'];?> </center></h3>
<h3><center>ID #:1031</center></h3>
<a href="Login.php"><h3><center><u>Sign Out</u></center></h3></a>
</div>
<div>
<br></br>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/table.css" type="text/css"/>    
<table class="features-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
<td></td>
<td><u><a href="RentalOrder101.html">Rental Order #101</a></u></td>
<td><u><a href="RentalOrder101.html">Rental Order #331</a></u></td>
<td><u><a href="RentalOrder101.html">Rental Order #432</a></u></td>
<td><u><a href="RentalOrder101.html">Rental Order #598</a></u></td>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Dates</td>
        <td>April 1 - May 31, 2011</td>
        <td>July 1 - July 5, 2012</td>
        <td>August 1 - December 31, 2012</td>
        <td>June 1 - October 31, 2013</td>          
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Venue Location</td>
        <td>Broward PAC</td>
        <td>Miniaci PAC</td>
        <td>Epstein PAC</td>
        <td>Parker Playhouse</td>           
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>$8,751.00</td>
        <td>$3,000.32</td>
        <td>$10,392.39</td>
        <td>$13,339.31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Paid/Unpaid</td>
<td>Paid</td>
<td>Paid</td>
<td>Paid</td>
<td><b>Unpaid</b></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
        <br></br>
        <a href="RentalRequest.html"><center><IMG src="Images/Request Rental.png" width=250 height=40></IMG></center></a>

    <br></br>
                <?php
        mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.

        // Include the footer and quit the script:
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="clear: both; height: 1px;"></div></div><!-- end #page -->';
        include ('includes/footer.html');
        exit();

        mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.

    } // End of the main Submit conditional.
    else {
        $url = BASE_URL . 'Login.php'; // Define the URL:
        ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
        header("Location: $url");
        exit(); // Quit the script.

    }
    ?>


    </div>
<!-- end #page -->
<?php
include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In case it matters, I am able to register and login successfully, so I know that I am seeing my database. I also know that I haven't fully converted my 2nd piece of code into php (there are still some static pieces), but I want to be able to see it run before I try to delve deeper.

Thank you for your help in advance.

EDIT - Just wanted to post a little more of my code below:

This is my config.inc.php:

```
<?php # Script 16.3 - config.inc.php
/* This script:
* - define constants and settings
* - dictates how errors are handled
* - defines useful functions
*/
// Document who created this site, when, why, etc. 
// ********************************** //
// ************ SETTINGS ************ //
// Flag variable for site status:
define('LIVE', FALSE);
// Admin contact address:
define('EMAIL', 'ds155@nova.edu');
// Site URL (base for all redirections):    
define ('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost:8888/sopshin_rental/');
// Location of the MySQL connection script:
define ('MYSQL', '../mysqli_connect.php');
// Adjust the time zone for PHP 5.1 and greater:
date_default_timezone_set ('US/Eastern');
// ************ SETTINGS ************ //
// ********************************** //
// ****************************************** //
// ************ ERROR MANAGEMENT ************ //
// Create the error handler:
function my_error_handler ($e_number, $e_message, $e_file, $e_line, $e_vars) {
// Build the error message.
$message = "<p>An error occurred in script '$e_file' on line $e_line: $e_message\n<br />";  
// Add the date and time:
$message .= "Date/Time: " . date('n-j-Y H:i:s') . "\n<br />";
// Append $e_vars to the $message:
$message .= "<pre>" . print_r ($e_vars, 1) . "</pre>\n</p>";
if (!LIVE) { // Development (print the error).
    echo '<div class="error">' . $message . '</div><br />'; 
} else { // Don't show the error:
    // Send an email to the admin:
    mail(EMAIL, 'Site Error!', $message, 'From: email@example.com');
    // Only print an error message if the error isn't a notice:
    if ($e_number != E_NOTICE) {
        echo '<div class="error">A system error occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience.</div><br />';
    }
} // End of !LIVE IF.
} // End of my_error_handler() definition.
// Use my error handler.
set_error_handler ('my_error_handler');
// ************ ERROR MANAGEMENT ************ //
// ****************************************** //
?>
```

This is my header.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="header">
</div>
        <link href="Styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function loginUser()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
document.getElementById("loginajax").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
//window.location='index.php';
}
}
//alert("user "+document.getElementById("user_email").value);
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxLogin.php?un=" + document.getElementById("user_name").value +  "&p="  + document.getElementById("password").value ,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<!-- end header.html -->
```

Finally, this is my ajaxlogin.php:

```
<?php # Script 16.8 - login.php
// This is the login page for the site.

require_once ('includes/config.inc.php');
require_once ('mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to the db.

// Validate the username:
if (!empty($_GET['un'])) {
$un = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $_GET['un']);
 } else {
$un = FALSE;
echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your username.';
        echo '<a href="register.php", class="welcome"> Register </a>';
        echo '<a href="forgotPassword.php", class="welcome">Forgot Password</a>';
}

// Validate the password:
if (!empty($_GET['p'])) {
$p = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $_GET['p']);
} else {
$p = FALSE;
echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your password!';
        echo '<a href="register.php", class="welcome"> Register </a>';
        echo '<a href="forgotPassword.php", class="welcome">Forgot   Password</a>';
 }

if ($un && $p) { // If everything's OK.
// Query the database:
$q = "SELECT user_name FROM user
                  WHERE (user_name='$un' AND password=SHA1('$p'))";
                $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query:   $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
                if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // A match was made.
session_start();

    // Put user in the session and send back a Welcome message
    $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_free_result($r);
    echo '<p class="welcome">Welcome ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '</p>';
    echo '<a href="logout.php", class="welcome">Logout<br></br></a>';
    echo '<a href="accounthistory.php", class="welcome">View11<br></br></a>';

} else { // No match was made.  Send back error message and login form.
    echo '<p class="error">invalid username and/or password.</p>';
    echo "<form><div align='left'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='user_name' required='required' value=''   class='Text' placeholder='Username' id='user_name'<br/>";
    echo "<input type='password' name='passwrd' required='required' value=''  class='password' placeholder='Enter Password' id='password'<br/>";
    echo "<input type='button' name='submitted' value='Sign In'  onclick='loginUser();'></div></form>";     
}

} else { // If everything wasn't OK.
    echo "<form><div align='left'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='user_name' required='required' value=''  class='Text' placeholder='Username' id='user_name'<br/>";
    echo "<input type='password' name='passwrd' required='required' value='' class='password' placeholder='Enter Password' id='password'<br/>";
    echo "<input type='button' name='submitted' value='Sign In'   onclick='loginUser();'></div></form>";        
}

mysqli_close($dbc); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

- I'm assuming that you do not have an .htaccess file that is forcing redirection to your login page. If you do, you may need to reconfigure this file.
- I would also like to see the code that is in your config.inc.php and header.html file (some programmers include php code in html documents).
- As phphelp states, you do not have an action attribute in your form, but you will not need this as long as your login logic is contained in the login page or one of the files that you are including. I do not see this logic in your code, but you state that you are able to login and register successfully. Where is this code?
- You will also need to set your $_SESSION variables manually after the user logs in. I see your code checks for variables like $_SESSION['user'], but I do not see where you are setting $_SESSION['user']. This may be contained in your login logic as well, but again, I do not see this logic in your code above.

In your second file (the page that you are trying to access) you may want to replace:

```
ob_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

With:

```
session_start();
ob_start();
```

On another note, you may want to take a look at the following code:

```
$url = BASE_URL . 'Login.php'; // Define the URL:
ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
header("Location: $url");
exit(); // Quit the script.
```

PHP header redirects should be sent before anything else. I have noticed that many times redirects will still work when data has already been sent to the user, but it is not recommended to do this.

As eddwin states, you will need add a redirect at the top of your login page. The header should only be sent after you check that the user has logged. Something like the following should be added to the top of your login page...

```
If (login_sucessfully() == true) {
    header("Location: go-to-this-page.html");
    exit; // Needs to be added because the redirect header that is sent, does not stop script execution
}
```

Comment: I added my header.html, ajaxlogin.php and config.inc.php to my original post above. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: It doesn't look like the issue is in your php code. You should rework your ajax functionality, so that javascript knows if the login sucessful or not. If the login was successful, you should use javascript to redirect your page (i.e: window.location.href="go-to-this-page.html") if not, display the error message in the container. By the way, jQuery makes the use of ajax calls (and everything else in javascript) much easier. You may want to look into it. http://jquery.com/

Comment: I tried out your suggestions, and it doesn't seem to be working. Part of my problem is that, even if I try to just go into the page by entering the URL, I am still directed back to the login page. So that's why I was thinking that it had something to do with my PHP.

Comment: In the page you are trying to access you have a redirect to the login page if $_SESSION['user'] isn't set. You may want to var_dump($_SESSION['user']); exit; in that else statement and ensure that your $_SESSION['user'] is being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to another page you need header() example.

header('Location: mypage.php');

And make sure you are not printing anything before header is place.as well for session_start();

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Which page would I put that on: the login, or the page that I am trying to get to? I also see that I have a header("location: $url") in my code. Am I replacing that code with what you suggested or is this its own addition?

Answer (score 0):

your form doesn't seem to have any action.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp